# password_verify keeps giving me an error even if i fill in the correct password

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to build a login form using php and i noticed after writing the basic code that it only gives me the error Wrong password! (which i setup) I stored my password in my database hashed using password_hash(pass, password_default) but it doesnt seem to verify my password. here is my code:
LoginHandler.php :

```
<?php
//include database
include 'database.php';

//start session
session_start();

//define variables
$username = $_POST['usernames'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if (empty($username) || empty($password)) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = "Vul alles in";
    header('Location: ../website/login.php');
} else {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR, 50);
    $stmt->execute();
    
    if ($stmt->rowCount() == 0) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = "Incorrecte gebruikersnaam!";
        header('Location: index.php');
    } else {
        $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if (password_verify($password, $user['password'])) {
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            if (isset($_POST['rememberme'])) {
                setcookie('username', $username, time() + 3600 * 24 * 30);
                setcookie('password', $password, time() + 3600 * 24 * 30);
            } else {
                if (isset($_COOKIE['username']) && isset($_COOKIE['password'])) {
                    setcookie('username', '');
                    setcookie('password', '');
                }
            }
            header('Location: index.php');
        } else {
            $_SESSION['error'] = "Wrong password!";
            header('Location: /website/login.php');
        }
    }
}
```

and for RegistrationHandler.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
//include database
include 'database.php';

$email = $_POST['email'];
$username = $_POST['usernames'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$hashedpass = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

if (empty($email) || empty($username) || empty($password)) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = "Vul alles in";
    header('Location: ../website/registration.php');
} else {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO login (username, password) VALUES (:username, :password)");
    $stmt->bindParam('username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam('password', $hashedpass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header('Location: ../index.php');
}
```

I have no clue why it doesnt verify my password since i think im using password_verify correct.

Comment: i forgot to say, database.php is just the database connection

Comment: Is your password column wide enough? The recommended width is 255. Anything less than 60 will give you trouble. Then use `var_dump()` to display the actual password you're trying to validate, and the hash you're trying to validate it against. Be sure you're working with the data you think you are.

Comment: Yup that was it in my database it was set to varchar(50) changed it to 255 and it works now (after truncating table and re registering)